# Guide in hiding will_paginate page links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination, will-paginate

Is there any way i can prevent the page links render from will_paginate to be displayed on the address bar? Just like when i navigate betweens tabs, when i implement tab-content, the links between the tabs are not being displayed out.

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain this better?

Comment: You could use javascript and ajax to replace the page content - but you lose the proper back button behavior and users cannot share a link to a specific page by copying the url. My recommendation is just get over the pretty URL OCD.

Comment: PS. that why any decent tabs implementation uses hashes or pushState to become stateful.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the CSS on the will_paginate objects displayed in browser to hide them.

Comment: Can i have guide on this?how do i hide it through css

Comment: All you need to do is change the CSS for the specific element on the html page to "display:none"